# .wrapper CSS will change the width of my bootstrap card, but not the height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
body {

padding-right: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;

background-color: #228B9D;

}

div.tron {
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 250px;
    padding-left: 250px;
}



.wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

div.card-block {

padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;

}
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card flex-row flex-wrap" >

             <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1482/1482003.svg" alt="sop" style="background-color: #324A5E;">

        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Description</p>

        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Hello, I'm very new to coding web pages and seemed to have run into a little issue I can't figure out. I'm trying to change the height of my card by using CSS. I've set the width to 1000px and it works just fine. however, when I input the height as 300px, it does not change anything with the card. is there any reason only the width can be changed and not the height? let me know if I should have included any more information. thanks!

Comment: So you want the wrapper to be not as high as the content it contains? In that case you will need to set max-height: 300px! You can then control the overflow behaviour with the overflow property

Comment: when you set the height of the card to: height: 300px it just does nothing?

Comment: @ShrewdStyle it sizes the box containing the title and description, but does not change the size of the picture and the footer.

Comment: @ShrewdStyle this is what it looks like when i set the height on the card https://imgur.com/a/uugwREY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can work out, it looks like some of your divs are not aligned correctly, i have reformatted it and i can resize the card-block with a height now

have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-galileo-16u87

also in your css you don't need div.tron for a class, you can just use .tron,
let me know if it is still not working like you wanted

Comment: ah yes, that did it! thank you so much - you're awesome!

Comment: @TechEng no problem, can you tick my answer so the issue is now resolved